# What are the correct titles for the attendee/guest relationship?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Apologies for the horrible title.

If I'm invited to an event and I bring a plus one, they're are my guest and I am a guest of the event's host. But what am I to my guest?

I've tinkered with 'invitee' or 'attendee' and even had 'host' suggested to me.

Are any of these on the right track? If not, what are my options?

Comment: ...Meal ticket?

Comment: Seriously though, can you provide more information on why you need this particular relationship defined? Is this for a practical reason, for instance, a speech or program at the event where this relationship needs a specific reference, or are you just curious?

Comment: "host" was the first thing that sprang to mine for me as well, but that seems wrong.  Realistically you'd say "my date" (even if its platonic) but that's ignoring the context you're trying to explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a term for the relationship you are asking about.  If the original invitee's guest is a (potential future, not necessarily actual) romantic partner, then (in America, at least) the guest would be the invitee's *date*, and the term could be used in the inverse direction as well.  This is only loosely tied to the fact of the original's host's invitation.  But of course the guest might be a person to which *date* would be inappropriate, and then no term seems any where near right.  If queried about it, a person would probably say something about being invited by the original invitee, being with them, etc, and would not try to name a particular role they fit into.

Answer (score 1):

If I were the person who invited you plus one person of your choice, I would consider both you and your "plus-one" to be my guests, making no distinction between you.  You could consider your plus-one to be your "companion" or "friend"; or "wife", "spousal unit", "significant other", "roommate", "old college buddy", etc. as whatever normal relationship there is between you calls for.  As mgkrebbs says, I don't believe that there is any specific term extant for the situation described.

Comment: Hm, if A is B's plus-one, does that make B A's [augend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/augend)?

Comment: @msh210: Plus-One for the word augend.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there seems to be no perfect definition for the relationship between an attendee and their plus-one.

I had to deal with this as I'm a developer for a ticket-selling website called Picatic. If someone purchased tickets for other friends/family/etc, we had to put some blurb on the ticket mentioning the name of who actually purchased the ticket.

This started as "Guest of X", but after reading this thread and doing some other searching, I've concluded that we will have to change it to "Courtesy of X" or "This ticket purchased by X" since both the purchaser and their invitees are "guests" of the event host / performer.

Answer (score 0):

Not to steal from @Hellion, but "companion" seems to be a good neutral term here. It does not imply any romantic or other relation, but simply expresses that they are *accompanying* (see? same root) an invited guest.